# Find Indices Of Columns Having Some Nonzero Element In A 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with dim (157,1944).

I want to get indices of columns that have a Nonzero element in any row.

example: `[[0,0,3,4], [0,0,1,1]]` ----> `[2,3]`

If you look each row, there is a Non Zero element in columns [2, 3]

So if I have

`[[0,1,3,4], [0,0,1,1]]`

I should get `[1,2,3]` because column index 0 has no Nonzero elements in any row.

Comment: So, the second row doesn't have any unique index that are non-zeros for that case? Could you add another not so simple case like let's say `[[0,0,3,4],[0,0,1,1]],[2,0,0,3],[0,3,1,3]]` and list down its expected output?

Comment: yes. In your case I will get [0,1,2,3]

Comment: I am not clear on how you have arrived at `[0,1,2,3]`. Could you clarify? Please edit the question to list all these down.

Comment: @Divakar IIUC, it is `[0, 1, 2, 3]` because each of these indices has some row where there's a nonzero element.

Comment: @AmiTavory Yeah that's what I could guess from the expected output, but let's get the clarification from OP. Also that term `unique` isn't fitting well I think.

Comment: @AmiTavory is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if your question is completely defined. However, say we start with

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,0,3,4], [0,0,1,1]])
```

then

```
>>> np.nonzero(np.all(a != 0, axis=0))[0]
array([2, 3])
```

are the indices of the columns for which *none* of the rows are nonzero, and

```
>>> np.nonzero(np.any(a != 0, axis=0))[0]
array([2, 3])
```

are the indices of the columns for which *not all* of the rows are zero (it happens to be the same for the example you gave).

Comment: I believe OP asked for your second case, and it's a good answer, but I think the "!= 0" is not necessary, since by default evaluating the "a" numpy array without any boolean comparison will also result in looking for "any" nonzero.    so    np.nonzero(np.any(a, axis=0))[0]